Best ways to prove$\frac{\sin x}{\cos3x}+ \frac{\sin3x}{\cos9x}+ \frac{\sin9x}{\cos27x} = \frac{1}{2}(\tan27x-\tan x)$
Only way I know to solve this by obtaining an expression for sinx/cos3x in term tan x and then substiting it for all the terms in LHS and canceling out which is very easy but doesn't feel exactly natural.But what are the other ways? What will be the easiest? Is there a way to simply see a way to other side at a glance? How is these types trig ratios are derived? Is there any identities of this pattern?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suggest finding the formulas that expresses $~\sin(3x)~$ and $~\cos(3x)~$ in terms of $~\sin(x)~$ and $~\cos(x).~$  Then, my first try, which might be problematic, would be to express both sides of the equation in terms of $~\sin(x)~$ and $~\cos(x),~$ and simply see where this leads.

Sorry.Initially I had written down the trig identity incorrectly.It should be -tanx inside the bracket at the end not (-tan3x)

I found this question on a model paper for an exam

Let us use $t$ for $\tan x$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan 3x-\tan x
&=\frac {t^3-3t}{3t^2-1}-t=-\frac{2t(t^2+1)}{3t^2-1}
=-\frac
{\displaystyle\quad 2\cdot\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}
\cdot \frac {\sin^2 x+\cos ^2x}{\cos ^2x}\quad}
{\displaystyle \frac {3\sin^2 x-\cos ^2x}{\cos ^2x}}
\\
&=-\frac {2\sin x}{\cos x(3\sin^2 x-3\cos^2x)}=\frac {2\sin x}{\cos 3x}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Compute now
$$
(\tan 27x - \tan 9x)+
(\tan 9x - \tan 3x)+
(\tan 3x - \tan x)
$$ using the above formula.

Thank you.But do you know of  any other identities of a pttern like this.I am curious


The method I found on the marking scheme
First, you obtain that sinx/sin3x=1/2(tan3x-tanx) and then you can obtain sin3x/cos9x and the next term in terms tan and then when you write LHS using this terms cancel out and RHS is obtained

Interesting enough.This question has been previously asked and this answer is given

Please don't post pictures of math on paper. Use MathJax to typeset the math. For one thing, users with vision disabilities cannot see the math on your photo, but they can still read content on a screen including math with MathJax. For another reason, answers are supposed to be editable. No one can edit your picture like they could edit a typed up answer.

Alright.I didn't know that.srory
